# What mail variable is needed to make sure I receive a copy as well when emailing an alias

Tags: email, variable, mailx

The alias includes a list of addresses and includes mine as well what mail variable do I need to make sure I still receive a copy of the message as well?

Comment: What mail system are you using? the MTA is probably most important, but MDA may also be useful.

Comment: Using Mail or mailx.

Comment: when sending an email to an alias the sender doesnt receive a copy of the message if the name is entered in as well, what mail internal variable do I need to set to make sure the sender receives the message too?

Comment: There are a couple of different mailx packages out there, but usually `set metoo` does this.